# Matlab loop not working properly

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop

```
largest = 0;
num = 0;
temp = 0;
num_flip = 0;

for x = 100 : 999

    for y = x : 999
       num = x*y;
       temp = num2str(num);
       num_flip = str2double(fliplr(temp));

       if num/num_flip == 1
          largest = num;
          one = x;
          two = y;
       end
   end
   end
```

I'm trying to find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers but for some reason my the loop stops at x = 924 and y = 962 but I know that's not answer. The code works fine for 2-digit numbers(10 : 99) though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not testing if **largest** is truly the largest with that code. As you go through the loops it is possible that a smaller  palindrome will be detected after a larger one, and you are reassigning ***largest*** to it.

Try this with an added test for whether a new palindrome is larger than the current ***largest***:

```
largest = 0;
num = 0;
temp = 0;
num_flip = 0;

for x = 100 : 999
    for y = x : 999
       num = x*y;
       temp = num2str(num);
       num_flip = str2double(fliplr(temp));

       if ((num/num_flip) == 1) && (num > largest)
          largest = num;
       end
 end
end
```

I removed these assignments

```
one = x;
two = y;
```

because it's not clear what they are for from your question.  Add them back if they are needed for a reason not shown.